# Inverted confusion matrix for really small dataset

Tags: cross-validation

I am working on a dataset that is only 84 samples large (very hard to get more samples at the moment).

It is physiological signal data and I am passing in the raw data as well as the Common Spatial Pattern transform of the result.

So these are the respective confusion matrices:
[image]
[image]

I am baffled, these are the results of a 10-fold cross validation using sklearn. How can my results be so perfectly inverted??

Answer (score 0):

It's because when I was KFold validating I forgot that my sample data is in order, so naturally some partitions are only going to have a large class imbalance. Therefore it will predict the opposite class in this case because I have 2 classes.

So your Confusion Matrix will be exactly the opposite of what you expect!